# View of frame not appeared to have set in awakeFromNib

Tags: nslayoutconstraint, awakefromnib

I am using autolayout in my view controller, to align a uiview as if it were a navigation bar (aligned to top, stretched to trailing and leading sides and 44 height).

I have subclassed this view, and during `awakeFromNib` I want to add subviews to it.

However, when I adding these subviews (also with constraints to the parent view) it doesn't work.

Initially I thought the constraints were programmed incorrectly, however, after logging the frame of the view like so:

```
- (void)awakeFromNib
{
    [super awakeFromNib];

    NSLog(@"%@", NSStringFromCGRect(self.frame));
}
```

I get the following output:

```
2012-11-27 03:25:25.976 myApp[8262:c07] {{0, 0}, {0, 0}}
```

Yet when I log in, for example, `touchesBegan:withEvent:` it logs the correct frame size.

Does anyone know what might be causing this?

I have also tried setting `setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints:NO` on all views involved. But nothing seems to work.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When `awakeFromNib` is called, the view is not yet created. The best way to get properties of any kind from the view in this method is to call `[self view]` before trying to access properties.

Comment: hi, carter, could you write more detail? and how to change the `view` which is ` awakeFromNib`'s subView frame ?

Comment: On reflection the best method to subclass is `viewDidLayoutSubviews`